# Error by sending Email in Drupal 7, but ok by Rules?

Tags: rules, emails

System messages (Restore Password, Registration) not sending to email and in Logs shows error. But email sending by Rules (Ubercart) very good. What's the problem?

> Message   Error sending e-mail (from user@example.com to
>   user@example.com).
>   Severity  error

Comment: You say the log shows an error. What is the error?

Comment: MESSAGE: Error sending e-mail (from xxx@hotmail.com to xxx@gmail.com).
SEVERITY: error

Comment: Does anyone know the answer to this? I'm having the same problem. Skywind, did you ever figure it out?